# Can a Muslim make dua and ask forgiveness for non-Muslims?

Tags: tafseer, non-muslim, hadith-interpretation, surat-at-tawbah

There is a verse in Quran:

> مَا كَانَ لِلنَّبِيِّ وَالَّذِينَ آمَنُوا أَن يَسْتَغْفِرُ‌وا
>   لِلْمُشْرِ‌كِينَ وَلَوْ كَانُوا أُولِي قُرْ‌بَى مِن بَعْدِ مَا
>   تَبَيَّنَ لَهُمْ أَنَّهُمْ أَصْحَابُ الْجَحِيمِ
>
> It is not for the Prophet and those who have believed to ask
>   forgiveness for the polytheists, even if they were relatives, after it
>   has become clear to them that they are companions of Hellfire.
>
> http://tanzil.net/#9:113

But there is a hadith in [Bihar al-Anwar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bihar_al-Anwar) from the Prophet (SAWW) asking forgiveness for Meccan pagans when bothered him with throwing stone to him at first times he invited them to religion:

> اللَّهُمَ‏ اهْدِ قَوْمِي‏ فَإِنَّهُمْ لَا يَعْلَمُونَ
>
> O Allah! forgive my people, they do not know.

Bihar al-Anwar, vol.20 p.21

How this verse and this hadith are compatible?

Comment: You should read these two successive ayats: [Tawba 113-114](http://quran.com/9/113-114)

Answer (score 5):

Look at the verse you cited more precisely, it then adds "**after it has become clear to them that they are companions of Hellfire**".

This is also stated about Ibrahim --peace be upon him-- when he promised he will ask Allah to forgive his father (uncle indeed) and this is the one respect we shouldn't follow him although he is a good pattern according to [60:4]:

> There is for you an excellent example (to follow) in Abraham and those
>   with him, when they said to their people: "We are clear of you and of
>   whatever ye worship besides Allah: we have rejected you, and there has
>   arisen, between us and you, enmity and hatred for ever,- unless ye
>   believe in Allah and Him alone": **But not when Abraham said to his
>   father: "I will pray for forgiveness for thee**, though I have no power
>   (to get) aught on thy behalf from Allah." (They prayed): "Our Lord! in
>   Thee do we trust, and to Thee do we turn in repentance: to Thee is
>   (our) Final Goal.

Asking for forgiveness for such people is like Noah --peace be upon him-- asking Allah for rescuing his son from the flood which is again forbidden for him (*although what he did was not a sin either, clearly*), see [11:37,40,45,46,47]:

> "But construct an Ark under Our eyes and Our inspiration, **and
>   address Me no (further) on behalf of those who are in sin: for they
>   are about to be overwhelmed (in the Flood)**."
>
> At length, behold! there came Our command, and the fountains of the
>   earth gushed forth! We said: "Embark therein, of each kind two, male
>   and female, **and your family - except those against whom the word has
>   already gone forth**- and the Believers." but only a few believed with
>   him.
>
> And Noah called upon his Lord, and said: "O my Lord! **surely my son
>   is of my family! and Thy promise is true,** and Thou art the justest
>   of Judges!"
>
> He said: "O Noah! He is not of thy family: For his conduct is
>   unrighteous. **So ask not of Me that of which thou hast no
>   knowledge!** I give thee counsel, lest thou act like the ignorant!"
>
> Noah said: "O my Lord! I do seek refuge with Thee, lest I ask Thee for
>   that of which I have no knowledge. And unless thou forgive me and have
>   Mercy on me, I should indeed be lost!"

Answer (score 0):

reference for this verse; chapter verse:
مَا كَانَ لِلنَّبِيِّ وَالَّذِينَ آمَنُوا أَن يَسْتَغْفِرُ‌وا لِلْمُشْرِ‌كِينَ وَلَوْ كَانُوا أُولِي قُرْ‌بَى مِن بَعْدِ مَا تَبَيَّنَ لَهُمْ أَنَّهُمْ أَصْحَابُ الْجَحِيمِ